# is not primitive.

Tags: abstract-algebra

The irreducible polynomial $X^4+X^3+X^2+X+1\in F_2[X]$ is not primitive.

sol) the power of $\alpha$ do not exhaust the nonzero elements of GF(16),
where, $\alpha^4=1+\alpha +\alpha^2 +\alpha^3$ and $\alpha^5=1$.
I didn't understand the solution at all. Can any one help me to understand what is the meaning of this solution.

Comment: What is **your** definition of "primitive polynomial" *in this case* ?

Comment: a polynomial $F(X)$  with coefficients in $GF(p) = Z/pZ$ is a primitive polynomial if its degree is $m$ and it has a root $ \alpha $ in $GF(p^m)$ such that ${0,1,\alpha ,\alpha ^{2},\alpha ^{3},\dots ,\alpha ^{p^{m-2}}$ is the entire field $GF(p^m)$

Comment: Should that be ${}$  "...such that $\;\{0,1,\alpha,\alpha^2,...,\alpha^{p^{m-2}}\} \;$is the entire field $\;GF(p^m)\;$ " ?

Comment: Well I am not sure about it.

Comment: Apparently you're talking about *primitive elements* in a fields extension. Primitive polynomial is a notion that I have seen defined for polynomials in $\;\Bbb Z[x]\;$ (or in any other polynomial ring over a UFD) and is not related to what you defined.

Answer (score 0):

According to *your* definition (a slightly odd one, imo) , observe that if $\;\alpha\;$ is a root of the polynomial  $\;f(x)=x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1\in\Bbb F_2[x]\;$ , then since we have

$$x^5-1=(x-1)(x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)=(x-1)f(x)$$

we then have

$$\alpha^5-1=(\alpha-1)f(\alpha)=0\implies \alpha^5=1$$

and thus the multiplicative order of $\;\alpha\;$ is $\;5\implies \{\,\alpha,\,\alpha^2,\ldots,\alpha^1=1\}\;$ has only five elements, and it thus cannot equal a field with $\;2^4=16\;$ elements